# how to insert a table with icons (red, green & blue) in html page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create a html page where I have three tables with images, and one button compare, on page load only two tables will be displayed, when the user clicks compare button then the third table should appear with three icons

Green : Highly Match
blue: Possible Match
red: No match

How do I include these icons in my html page, Can I do this using jquery? or any other way?

Please help me.

here is the code, here I am comparing finger prints

```
<td><table style="width: 100%;"><tr>
 <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;  border: none;" > Right Thumb</td>
<td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;  border: none;"><span style="width: 50%;  border:     none;"><img src="img/RIGHT_THUMB.png" alt="right thumb" height="120"/></span></td>
<td><table style="width: 100%;"><tr>
 <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;  border: none;" > Right Thumb</td>
<td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;  border: none;"><span style="width: 50%;  border: none;"><img src="img/RIGHT_THUMB.png" alt="right thumb" height="120"/></span></td>
<input type="button"  value="compare"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code that shows what is being compared? Question needs a lot of work adding details and some html.

Comment: I am comparing finger prints here

Comment: compare what to what? And then display what? Please put a bit more effort in. You provided a little bit of html from one table. There is not nearly enough information for anyone to help with

Comment: I am so sorry, compare the right thumb of main candidate with the right thumb of hit candidate, the images are in two different tables if user clicks compare then one of the icons should appear in the middle of the two images.

Comment: getting closer... compare image names? If not, what is actually being compared. And what determines red vs green vs blue. And where doe this get displayed? You really aren't making this easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery or javascript. First make that icons & table visibility false and then make them appear on compare button's click event. Or u can add that button dynamically using jquery or javascript.